# Edit shopping-cart-totals-table subclasses

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to edit the class in the button to buy, on /checkout/cart/, but when I go to the .phtml of that section, all I get is:

```
 <table id="shopping-cart-totals-table">
        <col />
        <col width="1" />
        <tfoot>
            <?php echo $this->renderTotals('footer'); ?>
        </tfoot>
        <tbody>
            <?php echo $this->renderTotals(); ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Where can I find the rendersTotal function?

Answer (score 3):

Totals are render from the following .phtml

```
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/total/default.phml
```

You can change the class name in this file.

```
 <?php echo $this->renderTotals(); ?>
```

renderTotals function is defined in

```
 app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Block/Cart/Totals.php
```